# Using getter for an unordered_map in c++ creates an invalid read of size 8

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, stdmap

I'm trying to use a getter for a field `std::unordered_map<std::string, User *> userMap` to find a user in it.

I tired doing:

```
   std::unordered_map<std::string, User *>::const_iterator found = getUserMap().find(userName);
```

but valgrind detected an invalid read of size 8.
However when I did this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, User *> tmpUserMap = getUserMap();
    std::unordered_map<std::string, User *>::const_iterator found = tmpUserMap.find(userName);
```

The invalid read went away.

The getter is a standard getter:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, User *> Session::getUserMap() const{
    return userMap;
}
```

If needed I can provide the valgrind data, i'm using c++11 on clion editor.

Comment: Don't return by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getUserMap` returns a **copy** of `userMap`. This means that the iterator you obtained can only be used with said copy.

So when you store the copy around and then use the iterator with it, everything works.

When you invoke `getUserMap` more than once you obtain *different* and temporary copies of the map. You may not use an iterator obtained from the first copy (which is now invalid, since its map was a temporary) to access the second copy. You get undefined behavior when you try, and that is the reason you see confusing errors.

This is the nature of returning by value, it always returns a new object and not the original. If you wish to read `userMap` directly, then consider returning a const reference to it instead:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, User *> const& Session::getUserMap() const{
    return userMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing this:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, User *>::const_iterator found = getUserMap().find(userName);
```

You are using the method `find()` of a temporary object. Therefore, the iterator that you get is invalid after the statement has been executed (see [the lifetime of temporary objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)).

In the other code, `tmpUserMap` is actuallty not a temporary object and the iterator is stil usable because its source has not been destroyed.

Why do you get a temporary object in the first snippset ? Because `getUserMap()` returns by value which will trigger the creation of a copy of `userMap`.